# Cannot load mod_rewrite Apache module

Tags: apache-http-server, php, htaccess, httpd, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use `mod_rewrite` module of `Apache24 server`, but I am not being able to load it. I know there have been many questions asked regarding this topic and I have gone through all of them but nothing seem to work. These are the steps that I have followed until now---

1. CHANGED `httpd.conf` file made these changes--

a. Uncommented `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

b. Changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

2. Restarted apache server
3. Checked loaded modules using command prompt command `httpd -M`. I can see there that the mod_rewrite module has loaded. I am attaching the image below.

[The screen shot of my command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvwCM.jpg)

But after performing all these steps I can't see mod_rewrite as loaded module in `phpinfo`.

[Screenshot of phpinfo file](https://imgur.com/a/DNaGg)

As it can be seen in the above pic there is no mod_rewrite loaded module.
Also as a wild hack I even tried rewriting URLs using `.htaccess` file but this is not working. Apache seems to ignore `.htaccess` file although I have put that file inside my root directory.

```
 Note: I am running `PHP` as an apache module
 Using `WAMP` stack
 Using `localhost` as server
```

I need this module badly for URL rewriting purposes. Can you guys suggest some other way to load this module?

I am cracking my head for the past two days. Do you think a re-installation is needed or has it got something to do with path dependencies. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have tried to rewrite URL from virtual host as well. But still it is not redirecting. I am adding the `Virtual host` setup below---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory "/Apache24/htdocs">
Options FollowSymLinks 
AllowOverride All
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/Apache24/htdocs"
ErrorLog "/Apache24/logs/error.log"
CustomLog "/Apache24/logs/access.log" combined
<directory "/Apache24/htdocs">

    <IfModule rewrite_module>
            Options +FollowSymlinks
            RewriteEngine On
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule rewrite_module>
            RewriteRule   ^working.php   fun.html
    </IfModule>

</directory>
# Rewrite Rules #####################
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^working.php   fun.html
# end Rewrite Rules #################   
</VirtualHost>
```

The above code does not redirect it to working.php when I try to run fun.html. It simply says `the requested URL /working.php was not found on this server.`.
Thanks in advance!